# Issue with resetting datagrid in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid

I am new to JSF and I am working on an application where a group of parameters placed in a datagrid can be either added or removed. Below is the initial level of screenshot:

[image]

When I click on RemoveInvoice of any of the existing list, the list present after that box should automatically take the position of the removed list. But in my case, a blank section is getting displayed as per the below screenshot:

[image]

[image]

My jsf code looks like:

```
    <div class="listing_Table">
        <p:dataGrid columns="3" layout="grid" id="addInvoicePanel"
            value="#{hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.invoiceDetailTOList}"
            var="invoiceDetail">
            <p:panelGrid rendered="#{!invoiceDetail.delete}">
                <div class="Table">
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel>
                                <span class="redColor">*</span>InvoiceType:</p:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{invoiceDetail.invoiceTypeID}"
                                filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="InvoiceType is required">
                                <f:selectItems
                                    value="#{hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.newInvoiceTypeList}"
                                    var="list" itemValue="#{list.typeId}"
                                    itemLabel="#{list.type}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel>
                                <span class="redColor">*</span>InvoiceNumber:</p:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceDetail.invoiceNumber}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="InvoiceNumber is required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel>
                                <span class="redColor">*</span>InvoiceAmount:</p:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceDetail.invoiceAmount}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="InvoiceAmount is required">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel>InvoicePath:</p:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceDetail.invoicePath}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel>
                                <span class="redColor">*</span>InvoiceDate:</p:outputLabel>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:calendar id="invoiceDate"
                                value="#{invoiceDetail.invoiceDate}" showOn="button"
                                readonlyInput="true" timeZone="IST" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="InvoiceDate is required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel value="ServiceTax:" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceDetail.serviceTax}">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:outputLabel value="TDS:" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceDetail.tDS}">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Row">
                        <div class="Cell"></div>
                        <div class="Cell">
                            <p:commandButton styleClass="Submit_button"
                                value="Remove Invoice"
                                action="#{hrOrganizationPaymentDetailController.removeInvoiceDetail(invoiceDetail)}"
                                update=":EditOrganizationPaymentDetailForm:addInvoicePanel" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:dataGrid>
    </div>
```

And my backend java code is:

```
public void removeInvoiceDetail(InvoiceDetailTO invoiceDetailTO)
{
    List<InvoiceDetailTO> invoiceDetailTOList = null;
    List<Long> deletedInvoiceDetail = null;
    try {
        invoiceDetailTOList = hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.getInvoiceDetailTOList();
        deletedInvoiceDetail = hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.getDeletedInvoiceDetailID();
        if (deletedInvoiceDetail != null && !deletedInvoiceDetail.isEmpty()) {
        } else {
            deletedInvoiceDetail = new ArrayList<Long>();

        }
        for (InvoiceDetailTO detailTO : invoiceDetailTOList) {
            if ((detailTO.getInvoiceDetailID() != null && detailTO.getInvoiceDetailID().equals(invoiceDetailTO.getInvoiceDetailID()))
                    || (detailTO.getUniqueID() != null && detailTO.getUniqueID().equals(invoiceDetailTO.getUniqueID()))) {
                detailTO.setDelete(true);
                if (invoiceDetailTO.getInvoiceDetailID() != null) {
                    deletedInvoiceDetail.add(invoiceDetailTO.getInvoiceDetailID());
                }
            }
        }

        hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.setInvoiceDetailTOList(invoiceDetailTOList);
        hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.setDeletedInvoiceDetailID(deletedInvoiceDetail);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER_.error("", e);
    }
}
```

Please advise where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `<p:panelGrid rendered="#{!invoiceDetail.delete}">`. Even with `rendered="false"` cell won't be removed from html page after rendering. If you open debugger in your browser (press F12 for Mozilla or Chrome) you can find empty cell there `<td class="ui-datagrid-column"></td>`. So you need to remove deleted item from your `#{hrOrganizationPaymentDetailBean.invoiceDetailTOList}` and update dataGrid.